# Trigonometric doubt on squaring both sides

Tags: trigonometry

I have the equation: $$\tan(x)+\sec(x)=1$$ What I tried was moving the $\sec(x)$ to the right side $$\sec(x)=1-\tan(x)$$ and here's the doubt, I decided to try squaring both sides, as after I will be able to apply $\tan^2(x)-\sec^2(x)=-1$, but when I squared both sides, the solution changed when I plugged it into Wolfram, $$\sec^2(x)=(1-\tan(x))^2$$ gives as solution from Wolfram $x=\pi k, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$ while the original equation gives $x=2\pi k, \quad k\in \mathbf{Z}$. Why is this?

Comment: $x=1$ has only one solution, but $x^2=1$ has two. What gives? The problem is that the former equation implies the latter, but the latter doesn’t imply the former.

Comment: why someone disliked the post? i wanna know what i did bad or something not to do it next time

Comment: Don't worry. By a long-standing tradition I have always upvoted every question I answer.

Comment: You don't have to square to solve this equation.

Comment: i know, but i was curious to as why, is there any other easier method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring an equation $f(x)=g(x)$ introduces all the solutions of $-f(x)=g(x)$. You need to filter out the solutions to this second, "unwanted" equation once you have worked out the solutions to the squared equation.

Comment: oh ok, so you mean that after squaring and getting that equation, and solving it, i should check in the solutions to know the extraneous solutions?

Comment: @Xetrez yes yes yes.